# global ajax handlers jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm using global ajax handlers like

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) { 
});

$(document).ajaxStart(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    $(".spinner").show();
})

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings, exception) {
    $(".spinner").hide();   
})
```

and it works well.

But i have some content which loaded from server by ajax, and with this content i'm loading some javascript which makes new ajax request. And when this ajax request start - global handlers not working :(

Comment: how is the (ajax-?)loaded javascript executed?

Comment: yes by ajax i'm loading not only html content but and js too

Comment: So I guess you're appending raw html, including <script>-tags, to your page? Then which scripts are that?

Comment: script with html which i received from server start new ajax request, which is not handle by global ajax event handlesr

Comment: Yeah, we got that. But we need the code of that script to help you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You should use jQuery's `live()` or `on()` method to bind your handlers. This will work for new elements.

If you use **jQuery 1.7** you should use the `.on()` method, if not use the `.live()`

#### Sample

**live()**

```
$(document).live("ajaxStart", function(e, xhr, settings, exception)  {
    $(".spinner").show();  
});

$(document).live("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings, exception)  {
    $(".spinner").hide();  
});
```

**on()**

```
$(document).on("ajaxStart", function(e, xhr, settings, exception)  {
    $(".spinner").show();  
});

$(document).on("ajaxComplete", function(e, xhr, settings, exception)  {
    $(".spinner").hide();  
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: it does not work even if i'm using document without ""

i'm using jquery 1.6.2

Comment: I have tested this with 1.6.2 (not working) and 1.7.1 (working). Can you try it with 1.7.1 ? I am looking why this happens, maybe a bug.

Comment: i have to read first change log in 1.7.1 ... how safe this upgrade could be. in 1.6.1 min was a bug this why i moved to 1.6.2 and i should move to 1.7.1 :) funny

Comment: it even does not work in 1.7.1 . When i'm loading content by ajax i also call some JS which run some plugin wich run another one ajax call. and start and stop (global ajax handlers) dos not work even in 1.7.1 :(